# Defaulting to default getter behavior if property does not exit

Tags: php, oop, setter, getter, magic-methods

I'm currently needing to extend a class to add functionality to it (I do not have access to the base class to modify it), and I'm running into an isssue with it.

Basically, I need the magic getter function to return a set of private variables if they are requested, but otherwise default to the default behaviour. I need these properties to be private so as to use the magic setter function to automatically sync some data.

That said, here's some example code:

```
class newClass extends baseClass {
    private $private1;
    private $private2;

    ...

    public function __get($name) {
        if($name == 'private1') return $this->private1;
        if($name == 'private2') return $this->private2;
        ... (and so on)
        // and here, it should default back to it's default behavior (throwing
        // an error on getting invalid/inaccessable property, etc.)
        // I cannot just use property_exists, because there may or may not be
        // private variables in the base class that should not be exposed.
    }
    public function __set($name,$val) {
        // I use this to do some automatic syncing when the two private variables
        // above are set. This needs to be triggered, hence the private variables
        // in the first place.
    }
}
```

I know, I could use getProperty/setProperty functions, but I would like this to remain as intuitive as possible, despite the argument that performing such operations is counter-intuitive. The two private properties are very much connected to each other. When one of them is set, it is logically going to affect the others.

As of right now, this is the only logical way I can think of to avoid getter/setter functions and maintain the closely bonded sync between properties. If you guys can think of anything else that may be a viable solution, feel free to suggest options :)

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: _remain as intuitive as possible_ magic is never intuitive.

Comment: By the way, what do you mean by "default behavior" the PHP default behavior, or your parent class?

Comment: @Boris: Perhaps the best wording is not intuitive. Perhaps I should have said 'logical'. When a pair of variables are closely linked as in my use-case, when one is updated, it logically invalidates the other if it is not updated as well.

And by "default behavior" I mean throwing it's native errors if a property is inaccessible, returning the property value if it is a public property, etc. so PHP's default behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP does not have a property builtin like other languages, __get and __set are indeed what you should use here. But it's a bit more work to accomplish therefore.

Your problem seems to be `property_exists` foremost. It's not easily possible to determine the publicity of properties from within the class (except with introspection). But you can use `get_object_vars` to filter out private variables from the base class at least:

```
 function __get($name) {
     static $r; if (!isset($r)) { $r = new ReflectionClass($this); }

     if (($p = $r->getProperty($name)) and $p->isPublic()) {
         return $this->$name;
     }
     elseif (method_exists($this, "get_$name")) {
         return $this->{"get_$name"}();
     }
     else trigger_error("inaccessible property ->$name", E_USER_NOTICE);
 }
```

For reverting back to default behaviour the best you can do is to manually output an error message.

Comment: I see what you are saying here, though what I don't get is this: _But you can use get_object_vars to filter out private variables from the base class at least_. get_object_vars gets according to scope, so it would return all non-static properties within the entire class, again exposing unwanted private vars. Unless you mean that get_object_vars will filter the parent's privates, in which case that may help more than I think it does as it stands currently. I have not played with get_object_vars in all the different scoping yet.

Comment: Yes it will not help a lot really. You will have to use `ReflectionClass` to get exact results.

Answer (score -1):

Don't do this, use getter/setters. They are exactly the same amount of work as what you are doing here.

Comment: [Getters and setters in PHP](http://berryllium.nl/2011/02/getters-and-setters-evil-or-necessary-evil/) are as much [not OOP as in other languages](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-09-2003/jw-0905-toolbox.html)

Comment: What he is writing here is one big getter/setter indexed by property name. Best to stick to what other programmers have learned to expect.